# How do the wave properties of an electron change with its motion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, wave-particle-duality

How do the wave properties of an electron change with its motion? What about when it is stationary?

Comment: *"stationary"* is an ambiguous word. An electron may be *at rest*. The typical terminology in QM uses the word *stationary* for the state of the quantum object, e.g. *stationary state*. In a stationary state the electron is not at rest. For instance in the ground state in an atom the electron has a nonzero kinetic energy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does a stationary electron exhibit wave-particle duality?

Yes, the electron has a [DeBroglie Wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) frequency, where $E=hf$,

$E$ being the total relativistic energy, so just the rest mass energy if the electron is at rest.

> If so, how do its wave properties change with its motion?

The energy and frequency will be greater the faster the electron moves.

$E = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, where $m$ is rest mass.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how its energy and frequency are related to its velocity?

Comment: yes, I added to the answer

Comment: I wouldn't include relativity here: if you talk about de Broglie wave, you are in non-relativistic regime, otherwise you must speak about bispinor wavefunction instead.

Comment: one should stress that the wave is a PROBABILITY wave, the probability of measuring an electron in a specific x,y,z is a distribution that displays wave properties.

Comment: @annav I disagree with the interpretation that the wave-function describing the dynamics the electron is a PROBABILITY wave. People legitimely ask whether the wave-function is a REAL thing. We don't know enough, for the moment, for answering in the positive or in the negative to this question. Another issue: the terminology **"probability wave"** is not exact. The wave-function comprises **amplitudes of probability**, endowed with **phases**. This is what brings similarity between QM and wave machanics (of course, there are also differences between QM and classical wave mechanics).

Comment: @Sofia  note that this is not a discussion about the wavefunction but about the measured probability distribution of an electron in space, described by  the de Broglie wave condition. It is about data, not theories of quantum mechanics.

Comment: @annav , the statement that "one should stress that the wave is a PROBABILITY wave" is not good expression. It is a statement in itself and reminds an old conception. There are people who even in our days believe in it. It's better to avoid it, and refer simply to wavelength and energy as DavePhD did.